# Cannot create new project after Eclipse update

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Yesterday, I was installing ADT for Eclipse. It all went well, until I clicked Check for Updates. After Eclipse rebooted, all the preferences are gone, I can't create new project, ADTs are gone. But when I try to download ADT from the Install New Software option, it says that I've installed it.

I've also reinstall Eclipse and same thing still occurs.

What can I do to fix this? I do not know what causes this whether it is ADT or Eclipse itself, because I can't even create new project for C++ or even Java.

I have Eclipse Indigo.

EDIT: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: have you checked preferences n path of android sdk..>??

Comment: @Aze I put it in Home folder. Oh I use Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Try deleting the meta-data folder inside the workspace.

Comment: Thank you. Already solved by deleting all Eclipse's related folders. And reinstalled it :)

Answer (score 0):

After installing ADT plugin go to windows > Android SDK Manager, after loading the packages click on install button, after installation is complete then check your problem is solve.